# How can i get or display the table to other display

Tags: php

this is my tables and the data of tables

table 1

```
| id | name | age |
| 1  | rey  | 13  |
| 2  | joel | 14  |
```

table 2

```
| time id | id | minutes |
|    1    | 1  | 3 mins  |
|    2    | 1  | 4 mins  |
|    3    | 2  | 5 mins  |
```

this is my question how can i display it like this in php code

view.php

```
NAME AGE   
rey  13   [VIEW] (click view to transfer to other page)
joel 14   [VIEW] (click view to transfer to other page)
```

and when i click the rey it will display like this and so on with joel

other.php

```
MINUTES  
3 mins  
4 mins
```

Comment: mysqli or pdo ?, what you have tried ?

Comment: SELECT CONCAT(t1.name, ' ',  t1.age,  ' is ', t2.minutes ) AS result FROM table1 AS t1 JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id. I think is that all you want?

Comment: @Sivabalan what is CONCAT sir?

Comment: It will concat the columns and static strings like . works in php for string concatenation

Comment: @Niklesh $time_id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE time_id = '$time_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);  this is so far i tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass corresponding ID from first page to second one:

***view.php***

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY name";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        ?>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>AGE</th>
                    <th>LINK</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                    echo '<tr>
                        <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['age'].'</td>
                        <td><a href="other.php?id='.$row['id'].'">[VIEW]</a></td>
                    </tr>';
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php
    }else{
        echo 'No results found.';
    }
?>
```

***other.php***

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die(mysqli_error($link));
        $query = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']." ORDER BY minutes";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            echo 'MINUTES<br>';
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                echo $row['minutes'].'<br>';
            }
        }else{
            echo 'No results found for given ID.';
        }
    }
?>
```

Don't forget to add proper parameters in `mysqli_connect()` function.

Comment: thank you sir but in adding in database in table 2 is it correct? in $id = $_POST['id'];
$minutes = $_POST['minutes']; $sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (id, minutes) VALUES ($id, $minutes) WHERE id = $id;

Comment: add right (your) host, user, password and database name, that's what I mean.

Comment: yeah it is connected to host just the adding sir it is correct?

Comment: how about adding a data in minutes sir? that will target the id through php?

Answer (score 1):

In the first page, a normal `select *` on the required table will suffice. This would get you the data required.

On the `view.php` page for that first table, display the `table1.name` and `table1.age` accordingly. For the link, you can have something along the lines of `server_url/other.php?id=<<id>>` where `<<id>>` is the corresponding `table1.id` gotten from the initial `select *`.

When processing the data for that page, a `select * from table2 where id = <<id>>` would suffice; where `id` in the conditions list is the foreign key which ties both tables.

Comment: how about add another minutes(table2) then the id(table1) is on rey(table1.name)

Comment: so far this is what i've done but cant add minutes

$id = $_POST['id']; $minutes = $_POST['minutes']; $sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (id, minutes) VALUES ($id, $minutes) WHERE id = $id;